# Content of SSL Certificate CA bundle file can be called CERTIFICATE (CHAINED) for Runcloud Custom SSL/TLS

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

Hi i am trying to secure my website with ssl from namecheap they sent me zip file that contain three files CA bundle File, Security Certificates and PKCS #7 Certificates

I am using runcloud.io for server managment. they have SSL/TLS section. 
screenshot below 
[runcloud ssl/tls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWES1.png)

They need two Things to implement SSL. one is PRIVATE KEY and Other is CERTIFICATE (CHAINED). I already have PRIVATE KEY that i generated during CSR file creation. My question is what will be content of CERTIFICATE (CHAINED). Should i put content of CA bundle File ? or CERTIFICATE (CHAINED) is not same as CA bundle File it is something else ?

My Server is Ubuntu 18.04 and Ngnix + Apache Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally figured out way,

[Sectigo formerly called Comodo Knowledge Base](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000zFJQ) Helps me,

So For CERTIFICATE (CHAINED) I had to combine the content of both CA bundle File, Security Certificates (a.k.a .crt File) Paste the content of .crt File on top then after that content of CA bundle File. It will be then your CERTIFICATE (CHAINED)